# Slope-stability, tilt-stability, and Bridgeland stability

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, triangulated-categories, coherent-sheaves

Following the definition of slope-stability ($\mu$-stability) and tilt-stability ($\nu$-stability) on page 8 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1585, does an object's tilt-stability imply its slope-stability (under certain conditions on the parameters)?  And as tilt-stability is a limiting case of Bridgeland stability conditions, does Bridgeland stability imply tilt-stability (again under certain conditions on the parameters)?